# Does anyone know what these spot on rotors are?

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, brake-calipers

I was finishing up detailing my car when I noticed this spot on the rear rotor. I checked all the rotors and then saw that the other rear rotor had a similar spot like this. Now at first when I saw it I thought immediately that it’s a hotspot but then doing more research it could be deposit from the brake pad. But I don’t know I can’t seem to find someone on any of these threads show a picture that has spots like these on their rotors. So any help is appreciated.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Has the vehicle been left parked for en extended period of time, while you went on holiday for example?

Comment: Sometimes I won’t drive the car for a week. I don’t know if that’s too long of a period of not driving the car?

Answer (score 0):

These are deposits from the brake pads. They will probably cause vibration as you brake. You might be able to pull the wheel off and use a wire brush on them to get it off, but it may require getting the rotors turned to get rid of it.

Comment: Yeah I drove the car and noticed some pulsation/vibration. But I’ll definitely give that a try and if not take it to get the rotors turned. Thank you.